# Tomcat Application status check

Tags: tomcat

Two tomcat servers are running in backend, which is loadbalanced in apache. Sometimes i can see application not responding, but java(tomcat) process is running. when i hit tomcat(application) servers in browser individually using ipaddress http://x.x.x.x:8080/ , it is keep on loading. I need to get an email trigerred when the tomcat went unresponsive. Kindly help me with this (what factors need to be checked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Tomcat [presentations](http://tomcat.apache.org/presentations.html) page and the *Monitoring Apache Tomcat with JMX* slides which include a lot of information for monitoring Tomcat nodes.

Items I would monitor in any Java application server:

1. Memory usage, including any OOMEs
2. JDBC connection pool depth and utilization
3. Session count
4. Basic response to HTTP/AJP requests